# Resumable HTTP upload

Tags: html, http

My server receives files after creating a web page with a `<form>` and `<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple />` stuff which is read by a browser over a HTTP connection.

The client browser posts these files via POST. Now, If I already have got in the server a part of the file (comparing with size and filename) in a previous browser session, is there a way to notify the client that I only want part of the file?

That is, some kind of HTTP response and headers in order to have the client resend the request with a different Content-Range.

The client is not under my control, it's a standard Web browser like chrome.

Comment: Not with a standard form, I don’t think so. With a custom client you could certainly create a protocol (on top of HTTP) that would allow that, but the standard form behavior isn’t that sophisticated.

Comment: I don’t understand the downvote... That said, I haven’t heard of an HTML-only solution for that, but you could add a JavaScript solution on top of the form, that sends only the appropriate range via `fetch()`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch, and the file API, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_API/Using_files_from_web_applications. It will take a lot of hand-coding stuff (and you need to come up with a channel for the server to tell the client about the missing range), but should be possible to do.